# Blocking static content in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

What's the best way to prevent users from downloading specific files in my Content directory?

Should I add a Web.config to /Content, like I already have in /Views?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="SecretFolder/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
      <add path="SecretFile.pdf" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Or should I create a custom routing rule?

Or is there an even better way?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what the [`<authorization>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t%28VS.71%29.aspx) is for in web.config.  This will give you granular control over what users can see which files. You can provide as little or much control as you need.

```
<location path="SecretFolder">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="admin" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

However, this assumes that you are implementing [ASP.NET authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx) using [`IPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx), which I would recommend if you need this sort of control over your content.

Comment: I don't currently have authorization setup, so this would be a bit more work than just dropping in a web.config.  Is there a performance reason that this might be preferable?

Comment: as a general method - most readings on the net recommend against using the Authorization element in MVC applications (great method for web forms) because of the multiple points of entries you can have. Yes - it would work prob just fine in this case but then potentially you start mixing auth. types in an app (since this method is not recommended to be used with the [Authorize] element

Answer (score 1):

Basically exactly as you have above - AS LONG as you don't have another route that would get to this via a controller. Judging from the file types and structure this doesn't seem to be the case (a concern is that you have two routes going to the same file - and using the authorization elements in a web.config is recommended against in MVC specifically for this reason)

You want to use exactly what is already used by MVC.
See the integration of "HttpNotFoundHandler" into your web.config at (I know.. you already have it) :
http://completedevelopment.blogspot.com/2011/06/using-views-outside-of-views-or-other.html

This is how content inside of your /Views folder is already blocked - so this is already 'mvc-ish'